# Elementary inequality about integrals of exponentials of concave functions (possibly connected to log concave distributions)

Tags: probability-distributions, inequalities, convex-analysis

I think the following inequality might be true and was hoping somebody might spot it or know a proof:

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is convex and suitably nice so that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-f(x)} dx = 1$$
Then is it true that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-f(x)} dx\ge 0$$
?

I also wonder what area of mathematics this might fit into or be a baby case of (perhaps the theory of logarithmically concave distributions)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

E.g., take any real $b>1$ and let $a:=2e^b$. Let $f(x):=a|x|-b$ for all real $x$.

Then $\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-f(x)} dx=1$ but $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-f(x)} dx
=1-b<0.$$